# Login from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am  trying to create a login that has username and password in JS but i don't know anything about javascript .
I have gotten the script from http://www.javascriptkit.com/cutpastejava.shtml but i have no idea how to apply it to Html or css with custom login.
Yeah i'm basically that new. I know its not safe as anyone can get the username and password from inspect but only me and few friends are going to know about it.
Thanks :D

Comment: First thing to learn: JavaScript and Java are completely different things. And second: The website you linked to seems very outdated. I would not rely on or learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use certain html tags to bring in the js/css files.

Bringing in a javascript file -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_javascript_file.js"/>
```

Bringing in a css file -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_css_file.css"/>
```

These files generally go in the head section of a html page.

A side note, Java and Javascript are two completely different languages. (You mentioned Java, when talking about Javascript.)